# how to sort in .each loop in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

This is my code in the view.  The Controller is simply getting the @category from the model.

This sort is not working.  Ultimately I need it to sort alphabetically by name.

```
    <%- @category.brands.sort_by{|brand| brand.name}.each do |brand| -%>
    <li <%= "class='current'" if brand == @brand %>><%= link_to(brand.name, [@category, brand]) %></li>
<%- end -%>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

I would use the **sort** function directly:

```
 <% @category.brands.sort { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name }.each do |brand| %>
   <li <%= "class='current'" if brand == @brand %>>
     <%= link_to(brand.name, [@category, brand]) %>
   </li>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you commonly sort by the same field 
You can define the `<=>` method ( and optionally include Comparable ) on the model and just call `model.sort` and it should work.

in the model:

```
class Brand < AcvtiveRecord::Base
  def <=> other
    self.name <=> other.name 
  end
end
```

the view:

```
<% @category.brands.sort.each do |brand| %>
<li <%= "class='current'" if brand == @brand %>>
  <%= link_to(brand.name, [@category, brand]) %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

If it wasn't an association I would sort it in the controller or have the model return it sorted then just display it with the view.

Then in the controller ( if this was not a subcollection )

```
  @brands = Brand.all.sort
```

the view:

```
<% @brands.each do |brand| %>
<li <%= "class='current'" if brand == @brand %>>
  <%= link_to(brand.name, [@category, brand]) %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is more "correct" than ghayes's method but will work about the same. Could do a hybrid of the approaches and just call sort with arguments in the controller, rather than defining the spaceship operator, if you aren't going to do this anywhere else.

Comment: haha the spaceship operator? I've never heard it referred to as sucht. I like it.